# When I write in csv how do I separate columns in Python

Tags: python, csv

My code is

```
import pymysql
conn=pymysql.connect(host=.................)
curs=conn.cursor()
 import csv
f=open('./kospilist.csv','r')
data=f.readlines()
data_kp=[]
for i in data:
    data_kp.append(i[:-1])


c = csv.writer(open("./test_b.csv","wb"))

def exportFunc():
    result=[]
    for i in range(0,len(data_kp)):
        xp="select date from " + data_kp[i] + " where price is null"
        curs.execute(xp)
        result= curs.fetchall()

        for row in result:
            c.writerow(data_kp[i])
            c.writerow(row)

        c.writerow('\n')



exportFunc()
```

data_kp is reading the tables name
the tables' names are like this (string, ex: a000010)
I collect table names from here.
Then, execute and get the result.

[image]

The actual output of my code is .. 
[image]

My expectation is

[image]

(not 3 columns.. there are 2000 tables)

I thought my code is near the answer... but it's not working.. 
My work is almost done, but I couldn't finish this part. 
I had googled for almost 10 hours.. 
I don't know how.. please help

I think something is wrong with these part

```
for row in result:
            c.writerow(data_kp[i])
            c.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the csv row?

Comment: Please show input, expected output and actual output (as csv, not as screen shots!).

Comment: I added the exaple row

Comment: well the actual output as csv is like this

Comment: a,0,0,5,9,3,0
2000-01-04
2000-01-05
2000-01-11
2000-01-12
2000-01-13
2000-01-14
2000-01-17
2000-01-18
2000-01-19
2000-01-20
2000-01-21
2000-01-24

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ You may find that relevant

Answer (score 0):

The [`csvwriter.writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) method allows you to write a *row* in your output `csv` file. This means that once you have called the `writerow` method, the line is wrote and you can't come back to it. When you write the code:

```
for row in result:
    c.writerow(data_kp[i])
    c.writerow(row)
```

You are saying:

> "For each result, write a line containing `data_kp[i]` then write a
>   line containing `row`."

This way, everything will be wrote verticaly with alternation between `data_kp[i]` and `row`.

What is surprising is that it is not what we get in your actual output. I think that you've changed something. Something like that:

```
c.writerow(data_kp[i])
for row in result:
    c.writerow(row)
```

But this has not entirely solved your issue, obviously: The names of the tables are not correctly displayed (one character on each column) and they are not side-by-side. So you have 2 problems here:

**1. Get the table name in one cell and not splitted**

First, let's take a look at the documentation about the [`csvwriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects):

> A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects

But your `data_kp[i]` is a `String`, not an "iterable of `String`". This can't work! But you don't get any error either, why? This is because a `String`, in python, may be itself considered as an iterable of `String`. Try by yourself:

```
for char in "abcde":
    print(char)
```

And now, you have probably understood what to do in order to make the things work:

```
#  Give an Iterable containing only data_kp[i]
c.writerow([data_kp[i]])
```

You have now your table name displayed in only 1 cell! But we still have an other problem...

**2. Get the table names displayed side by side**

Here, it is a problem in the logic of your code. You are browsing your table names, writing lines containing them and expect them to be written side-by-side and get columns of dates!

Your code need a little bit of rethinking because `csvwriter` is not made for writing columns but lines. We'll then use the `zip_longest` function of the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module. One can ask why don't I use the `zip` built-in function of Python: this is because the columns are not said to be of equal size and the `zip` function will stop once it reached the end of the shortest list!

```
import itertools

c = csv.writer(open("./test_b.csv","wb"))

# each entry of this list will contain a column for your csv file
data_columns = []

def exportFunc():
    result=[]
    for i in range(0,len(data_kp)):
        xp="select date from " + data_kp[i] + " where price is null"
        curs.execute(xp)
        result= curs.fetchall()

        # each column starts with the name of the table
        data_columns.append([data_kp[i]] + list(result))

    # the * operator explode the list into arguments for the zip function
    ziped_columns = itertools.zip_longest(*data_columns, fillvalue=" ")

    csvwriter.writerows(ziped_columns)
```

**Note:**
The code provided here has not been tested and may contain bugs. Nevertheless, you should be able (by using the documentation I provided) to fix it in order to make it works! Good luck :)